# AWS DynamoDB read newly inserted record

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Since i am new to AWS and other AWS services. for my hands on , prepared dynamodb use case. Whenever records insert into Dynamodb, that record should move to S3 for further processing. Written below code snippet in java using KCL

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        KinesisClientLibConfiguration workerConfig = createKCLConfiguration();
        StreamsRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory = new StreamsRecordProcessorFactory();

        System.out.println("Creating worker");
        Worker worker = createKCLCWorker(workerConfig, recordProcessorFactory);

        System.out.println("Starting worker");
        worker.run();
```

### }

```
public class StreamsRecordProcessorFactory implements IRecordProcessorFactory {


    public IRecordProcessor createProcessor() {
        return new StreamRecordsProcessor();
    }
}
```

---

method in StreamRecordsProcessor class

```
 private void processRecord(Record record) {
            if (record instanceof RecordAdapter) {
                com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Record streamRecord = ((RecordAdapter) record)
                        .getInternalObject();

                if ("INSERT".equals(streamRecord.getEventName())) {
                    Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes
                            = streamRecord.getDynamodb().getNewImage();

                    System.out.println(attributes);
                    System.out.println(
                            "New item name: " + attributes.get("name").getS());


                }
            }
        }
```

From my local environment , i can able to see the record whenever we added the records in dynamodb. but i have few questions.

1. How can i deploy this project into AWS.
2. What is procedure or any required configuration from AWS side.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You haven't posted enough information on what the code does for anyone to help you.  Surely that code snippet alone isn't doing what you described. For one, there are no references to any DynamoDb related APIs in what you have provided.  Please provide more detail, i.e. show more of the code.

Comment: @Ashaman Kingpin .. thanks for your comments.. added more details ..From my local i can read dynamodb data. 1. i want to re direct to some S3 location. 2. how can i deploy my application in aws

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use AWS Lambda as the integration point between Kinesis that ingest data from the DynamoDB stream and your Lambda function that reads data from the stream and pushes into a Kinesis Firehose stream to be ultimately deposited in S3.  Here is an [AWS blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/persist-streaming-data-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-kinesis-firehose-and-aws-lambda/) that can serve as a high-level guide for doing this.  It gives you information about the AWS components you can use to build this and additional research on each component can help you put the pieces together.

Give that a try, if you get stuck anywhere, please add a comment and I'll respond in due time.